# rsa with biginteger accepting p & q from user

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, rsa, biginteger

what i am trying is to encrypt current date and time with rsa and use this cipher text to enter in another application to authenticate the user.

here is the code. I am noobie with java so i copied it from Internet and have made few changes to.

Program -

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;


public class RSA3
{
public BigInteger n, d, e;

private int bitlen = 16;



 /** Create an instance that can both encrypt and decrypt. */

 public RSA3(int bits) 
{
     bitlen = bits;
    SecureRandom r = new SecureRandom();
 Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
 String number1, number2;
 System.out.println("Enter first number");
 number1 = in.nextLine();

 System.out.println("Enter second number");
 number2 = in.nextLine();

 BigInteger p  = new BigInteger(number1);
 BigInteger q = new BigInteger(number2);
 //BigInteger p = new BigInteger(bitlen / 2,100,r);
    //BigInteger q = new BigInteger(bitlen / 2,100,r);
    n = p.multiply(q);

 System.out.println("\n n="+n);
    BigInteger m =  (p.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)).multiply(q.subtract(BigInteger.ONE));
  System.out.println("\n m="+m);
    e = new BigInteger("3");
    while (m.gcd(e).intValue() > 1) 
 {
         e = e.add(new BigInteger("2"));
    }
  System.out.println("\n e="+e);
   d = e.modInverse(m);
  System.out.println("\n d="+d);
 }




  /** Encrypt the given plaintext message. */

  public synchronized BigInteger encrypt(BigInteger message) 
  {System.out.println("\n 2nd enc");
     return message.modPow(e, n);

   }



  /** Decrypt the given ciphertext message. */
  public synchronized BigInteger decrypt(BigInteger message) 
  {System.out.println("\n2nd dec");
   return message.modPow(d, n);

  }




  /** Trivial test program. */
 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
  RSA3 rsa = new RSA3(1024);
 DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHH");
   //get current date time with Date()
  Date date = new Date();
   System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));


  String text1 = dateFormat.format(date);
  System.out.println("Plaintext: " + text1);
  BigInteger plaintext = new BigInteger(text1.getBytes());

   BigInteger ciphertext = rsa.encrypt(plaintext);
  System.out.println("Ciphertext: " + ciphertext);
  plaintext = rsa.decrypt(ciphertext);

    String text2 = new String(plaintext.toByteArray());
   System.out.println("Plaintext: " + text2);
  }
  }
```

**If i take values for p & q from user as i have done in code. something is wrong with the ciphertext.
but if i go with BigInteger(bitlen / 2,100,r); it working fine.
but with this random number every time ciphertext generating is new. i dont want in this way**
i want p & q of my own choice

i think i have messed up with biginteger somewhere idk.
please let me know if there any other way i can do this.

I can not find the logical error here
please help
thank you

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is with your current code. Please make that clearer and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: ty for quick reply and sorry for my poor english

Comment: Do you want to use this RSA implementation in a project or is this purely academical? Textbook RSA is broken. For RSA to be secure a padding scheme such as OAEP must be used. Java provides all the necessary things to do this through the [Cipher class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html).

Comment: Your code works. You probably made an error typing in the two long primes.

Comment: When posting to stackoverflow, please describe your problem as well as you can. "something is wrong [with the ciphertext]" is never a good error description.